# Paypal Sandbox payment state pending

Tags: java, rest, paypal, sandbox

I am using the (Java) Rest API to perform payments directly from credit cards in the sandbox. The payments all receive "pending" status, which according to the docs (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment) is not even a valid state to be returned by the payment create call. Payment review is disabled.

I would like to see the process through and complete the transaction. How do I do that in the sandbox? Or should I receive a different state right away?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: I got the same issue and couldn't find any solution, except to change the currency to match the test account's country. As I'm canadian, my test transactions involved canadian dollars even if the sandbox merchant account is set to US. Switching from CAD to USD made all my next transactions be 'approved' directly.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Under http://developer.paypal.com, Application tab, find out the email associated to the REST app.
Now click on "Sandbox accounts", Click on the REST app email, click on "Profile" link.
Select "Setting" tab, and turn off "Payment review". You shall get "Approved" payment and "Completed" Sale json object.

Answer (score 1):

this is the same issue with [paypal status is pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380713/paypal-status-is-pending/23822017) so answer should be the same, just check the seller's selling preferences on the sandbox account like Max-P said, this is just different currency and config issue on paypal