# paypal status is pending

Tags: objective-c, paypal

hello everyone in my application i have to use Paypal for Norway currency(NOK) and everything is fine but when i used sandbox for testing the Paypal the state comes as pending while when i tried the same code for US Dollars the state is approved why this happening.
Here is my code and response

```
  @try
   {
    self.resultText = nil;
    NSUserDefaults *defpay=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *mon=[defpay objectForKey:@"month"];

    app *ap=[app new];
   dictpay=[ap paypal:mon category:_strcategoryid1 catid:_strpostid1];
    NSString *strprice=[dictpay objectForKey:@"price"];
    _lbl.text=strprice;
    NSLog(@"%@", _lbl.text);

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:strprice];
     //payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"12"];
    payment.currencyCode = @"NOK";
    payment.shortDescription = @"Payment";

    if (!payment.processable)
    {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.
    }

    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
    self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = self.acceptCreditCards;

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
    paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                   configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                        delegate:self];

    // Present the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


  }
   @catch(NSException *e)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",e.reason);
    }
```

> Here is the response which i got for NOK

```
     client =     {
         environment = sandbox;
         "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.0.5";
          platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
            };
            response =     {
       "create_time" = "2014-04-30T05:43:49Z";
       id = "PAY-7DX14671UN8535156KNQI3FI";
        intent = sale;
        state = pending;
        };
        "response_type" = payment;
       }
```

Comment: The sandbox seller account must be configured in a way that causes you to accept payments that are not in the USD currency.  If you login to the seller account do you see the transactions with Accept and Deny buttons next to it?

Comment: can anyone help me in this.. i stuck here and dont know what to do

Comment: Are you going to acknowledge the question I asked you so I can try to help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, the problem is the buyer is buying buy using a currency which is not the default currency of the seller, and by default paypal set something like manually approve different currencies, as they have conversion fee.

Login to your sandbox account, and click on profile then choose My Selling Preferences and on that page click on payment receiving preferences. And there choose

Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold
Yes, accept and convert them to  blabla

After this your tests will be back to normal and they will be approved too

Screenshots for settings:

[image: First Step]

[image: Second Step]

[image: Last Step]

Dont forget to save your settings after changing :)

Comment: @Rick4444  i have added screenshots

Comment: i am not getting this type of profile page. please see screen shots of my profile page

Comment: @Rick4444 where are screenshots?

Comment: i am not able to find this type of profile page can you give me the link of that page

Comment: @Rick4444 sandbox.paypal.com and login with your merchant/seller test account

Comment: i am not able to find this type of profile page can you give me the link of that page

In my profile page there is no option for "My Selling Preferences"..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54324/discussion-between-rick4444-and-stephanruhl).

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

The answer that **@stephanruhl** provided is correct but the **PayPal** made some changes and those who are not finding useful its instructions follow the steps below.

## Answer

To make this payment with status completed we need to login to your **PayPal Account** go to **My Account -> Profile -> My Selling Tools -> (Getting paid and managing my risk) Block payments** and hit **update**:

The following screen will pop up:
[image]

Scroll to the section **Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold**
and select **YES**

By doing this you will be able to automatically confirm your payments without reviewing each one (**Remember: Payment Review must be disabled**). If haven't disabled yet the **Payment Review** the follow these steps:

Under http://developer.paypal.com go to your Application. Click on **Sandbox accounts** and choose your **business email**, click on **Profile** link. Select **Setting** tab, and turn off Payment review. You shall get ***Approved*** status of **PayPal Payment** and ***Completed*** **Sale JSON object**. (Original Post: [Paypal Sandbox payment state pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193446/paypal-sandbox-payment-state-pending))

Hope it helps :)