# How to capture paypal webhook?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, webhooks

I've integrated PayPal Smart Buttons in my website, both `createOrder` and `Capture` are processed on the server side, when a payment has been completed the transation is available on business sandbox account and the `webhook` event is registered in Webhooks Events page.

The `webhook` `POST` url is subscribed in dashboard to all event and to test it in `localhost` i use [webhookrelay](https://webhookrelay.com/).

The issue is that i get the `webhook` called only when the event comes from the Webhook Simulator and not from an actual payment from Smart Button.

So my server receives webhook calls only from the simulator and is **NOT triggered** from a Smart Button payment.

I'm in sandbox mode and all payments and Smart Buttons are in sandbox mode.

Here is my Smart Button code:

```
paypal
  .Buttons({
    style: {
      shape: "rect",
      color: "gold",
      layout: "horizontal",
      label: "paypal",
      tagline: false,
      height: 52,
    },
    createOrder: async function () {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://www.example.it/payment/paypal/order/create/" + orderID,
        {
          method: "post",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      return data.id;
    },
    onApprove: async function (data) {
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://www.example.it/payment/paypal/" +
          data.orderID +
          "/capture/",
        {
          method: "post",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );
      const details = await res.json();
      if (localStorage.STBOrder) {
        localStorage.removeItem("STBOrder");
      }
      $("#modalPayments").modal("hide");
      $("#modalSuccess").modal("show");
    },
    onCancel: function (data) {},
  })
  .render("#paypal-button-container");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you are capturing on the server side, there is no real motivation to use webhooks. The response of your API call to do the capture is already authoritative; a webhook provides no useful additional information
- If you insist on implementing webhooks for some reason, you need to register a listener for the events you want to receive. There is an API for managing webhook registrations: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#webhooks_post , or you can try the steps in this guide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#subscribe-to-events
- Again, implementing asynchronous webhooks is completely unnecessary when you have already implemented a synchronous capture API call on your server.

Comment: but if someone completed the order but closed the page before onComplete method has been completed, i'd have a successful payment in paypal but if i place to confirm the order preparation on capture the order will never be prepared.. and i have to set order in "preparing" status only when i'm sure that the user has paid

Comment: The webhook has been yet registered through the dashboard but only works with Webhook simulator..

Comment: "but if someone completed the order but closed the page before onComplete method has been completed, i'd have a successful payment in paypal" -- this scenario does not occur with server-side captures.

Comment: So until the order will be captured the payment will not be completed right?

Comment: Let's pretend the answer is 'no'. What would the purpose of having a capture step be?

Comment: But what if you want to be informed about later events like a refund? You would need a webhook to catch events like this, no? This is a scenario on marketplaces where anybody can sell to anybody and the marketplace captures the orders and sends the money directly to the seller. How can the marketplace detect if an order has been refunded if not by a webhook?

Comment: It can't -- unless it initiated the refund with its own API call, of course. This is a separate conversation from all the above.

Comment: @PrestonPHX There is one scenario I'm worried about: If Capture Order (called from backend) is successful the response contains order status as well as capture status. The capture status can have value `PENDING`. Is there any PayPal documentation which says this can't happen? I didn't find anything...

Comment: If an order is complete and its capture is in pending status, there will be a details parameter with the reason it is pending. For more information, review the transaction in the www.paypal.com account interface which may require action.

Comment: Ok. I can notify user about that. But eventually I need to send request to accounting app on successful capture (which will happen in this case after they reviewed the transaction). So in this case implementing webhook makes sense, right?

Comment: Is there any example request of pending capture? I didn't find any in PayPal docs and also I didn't find any way to reproduce this behavior in sandbox.

Comment: The webhook PAYMENT.CAPTURE.COMPLETED will trigger when a pending payment is completed. PAYMENT.CAPTURE.REVERSED , .DENIED , and .REFUNDED are other possibilities.  There is a webhooks simulator to generate sample events.  If you want to trigger a pending payment you could try using a currency the account has no balance in, such as GBP or EUR

Comment: Triggering pending payment is not possible using different currency anymore. One day it probably was (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23822017), but the "Preferences for receiving payments" have changed since.

Comment: Ah, yes "ask me" for each one is gone. Probably for the best. Well, going to the list of sandbox accounts https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts -> Manage accounts -> ... -> View/Edit account -> Settings -> Payment Review -> "On" , may work.

Comment: Using that option for whatever account gives me this error on capture order: `{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"issue":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","description":"The request was refused"}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",}`